# Seek details in SPIFFS for a specific date

Tags: esp8266

I have a `ESP8266`,

I've  stored the below details in `SPIFFS`.

How can I seek all details like employee number ,name ,age for a specific date?

**Structure I am using ,**

```c
struct
{

char date[4];

char emp_number;

char name;

char age;

}std_detail;
```

**Details that stored in SPIFFS**

```
2019-10-21,employe number1,name,age

2019-10-21,employe number2,name,age

2019-10-21,employe number3,name,age

2019-10-22,employe number1,name,age

2019-10-22,employe number2,name,age

2019-10-22,employe number3,name,age

2019-10-22,employe number4,name,age
```